# How can I add a tag to the specified branch

Tags: git

All, `Git tag xxxx` is add a tag . But I want to how to add a tag to a branch. thanks.

Currently. I can switch the branch .

```
git checkout branchA
git tag xxxx
git push orgin --tags
```

Seems xxxx tag is add tag to the origin . right ? thanks.

Comment: Anyone please tell me why down-vote my question. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags do not point to branches, but rather to separate commits. When you do `git tag xxxx` in `branchA`, you mark a particular commit that is currently on top of that branch. When you make another commit in that branch, your tag still points to the original commit.

Therefore, tags are meant to mark points in you history that do not change. For example, when you release a 1.0.5 version of your product, you want to mark that point in codebase in a solid way, so you can look it up later.

Answer (score 3):

You must think of tags as branches that do not change. Creating tags from a specific branch makes sense, but pushing tags to a specific branch does not.

To understand that, take a look at the way your local references are set. You may notice that there's no branch notion related to your tags refs (`.git/refs/tags/`).